# Alpha channel set to below 0.1 results in invisible object

Tags: texture-painting

I encountered a problem I do not know why when creating image in Shader Editor,

I set alpha value between 0<=Alpha<0.1 in Shader Editor, the object is invisible from texture Paint mode, as seen below,

[image]

[image]

But if if set Alpha>0.1, the object become visible as shown below, but it colors blue

[image]

[image]

So I don't know why it become invisible if alpha value less than 0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shaders typically have a clipping value set for low alpha values. If the alpha is below the clipping threshold, the pixel won't be rendered. This is an optimization which helps speed up rendering and can help give sharper transitions on textures with transparency.

Comment: This makes sense however I can not seem to find this is stated in the doc.